# Some of my classes are not loading correctly when I run Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I recently upgraded this application from Rails 3.2 to Rails 4.1, but I'm having some problems running RSpec.

My app has over 20 models, all tests run fine except for one model, called `AlunoPos`:

```
# encoding: utf-8
class AlunoPos < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :identificador

  (...)
end
```

This class has 3 attributes, and of course inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base`. However, when I debug with `binding.pry` in one of my tests, I get these results when trying these things:

`AlunoPos.methods - Object.methods` => `[]`

`AlunoPos.class` => `Class`

It's like Rails loaded this model as a skeleton, empty class, and I'm not doing any stubs or mocks that could explain this.

This is the test I'm running btw (it fails when FactoryGirl tries to set the attributes):

```
# encoding: utf-8
require 'spec_helper'

describe AlunosPosController do
  describe "POST desmatricular" do

    before(:each) do
      @aluno = FactoryGirl.create :aluno_pos
      @params = {:matriculas => [@aluno.matricula]}
    end

    it "deve retornar status '200 OK'" do
      post :desmatricular, @params

      response.should be_success
    end

    (...)
  end
end
```

This also happens with another class that's not a model, but that's it. Over 20 models and these 2 classes are the only ones to have this issue, and there's nothing different about them that could explain this too. Except for obvious different business logic, they're all very similar.

What can I do about it? I know it's not a problem with my schema, as I already double checked it, Rails doesn't even seem to be loading ActiveRecord for the model and there's a non-activerecord class suffering from the same issue.

EDIT: Adding Factory code:

```
# encoding: utf-8
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :aluno_pos do
    sequence(:matricula) { |m| m }
    association :identificador
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you post the relevant code from the factory definition?

Comment: Yes, I just updated the question with this code, but again, it's the same as all the other factories, changing only the model name and fields. I don't think it's a FactoryGirl related issue, because there's another class that isn't even an ActiveRecord model having the same issue (Rails loads it without the static methods it has)

Comment: Are there another classes with the same name?

Comment: Very odd. Does your test work if you use `AlunoPos.create` instead of `FactoryGirl.create`?

Comment: No, the class AlunoPos doesn't have the method create, if I do AlunoPos.new, it's the same as doing Class.new, both are returning an empty class definition. This also only happens in the test environment, development and staging are fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. Someone re-declared those classes in a random spec test, with an empty body. Don't ask me why they did it, but I removed it and it now works.

The reason why it was working before is *probably* because this test was probably one of the last ones, so it didn't break anything, but now I set RSpec to randomize the order that the tests are run, and it's declaring these empty classes before the real thing. Another reason I can think about is that I changed RSpec version from 2.X to 3.3, it may have changed the load order for Rails classes.

**Bottom line:** This sort of thing can happen if the class was re-declared, and most important of all, *be wary of legacy code*.